# node-gcm send message only 1 device?

Tags: android, node.js

I use node-gcm to send message to Android devices, everything work fine when send message to 1 device.

```
var message = new gcm.Message({
    collapseKey: 'demo',
    delayWhileIdle: true,
    timeToLive: 3,
    data: {
        price: 'message'
    }
});             
message.collapseKey = 'demo';
message.delayWhileIdle = true;
message.timeToLive = 3;

getGcmIdFromDB(ka,function(dat){
    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dat));
    var items = Object.keys(obj);
    items.forEach(function(item) {
        registrationIds.push(obj[item].gcm_regid);
        sender.send(message, registrationIds, 1, function (err, result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
    });                
});
```

My script successfully send message to a client Android device,but when I send message again to another device the message still sent to the first device? Maybe my code doesn't refresh, my node-gcm results this log.

```
{
    multicast_id: 7032530745780722000,
    success: 3,
    failure: 0,
    canonical_ids: 0,
    results: [ 
        { message_id: '0:1388475224605981%f11e78b0002efde3' } 
        { message_id: '0:1388475224605981%f11e78b0002efde3' } 
        { message_id: '0:1388475224605981%f11e78b0002efde3' }
    ]
}
```

Please help?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing the following:

```
items = [{gcm_regid: 1}, {gcm_regid: 2}, {gcm_regid: 3}];
```

What your code may do is first send a notification to device 1, then notifications to device 1 and 2 and finally notifications to devices 1,2 and 3.

Probably what you want to do is to specify all the ids at once*:

```
items.forEach(function(item) {
    registrationIds.push(obj[item].gcm_regid);
}
sender.send(message, registrationIds, 1, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Also, `registrationIds` declaration/initialization dos not appear in your code, so before you use it check it is correctly initialized:

```
getGcmIdFromDB(ka,function(dat){
    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dat));
    var items = Object.keys(obj);
    var registrationIds = [];
    items.forEach(function(item) {
        registrationIds.push(obj[item].gcm_regid);
    }
    sender.send(message, registrationIds, 1, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });                
});
```

---

*) If I'm not wrong, you can only specify 1000 id's on each `send` call, so you may want to check that.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear where you are declaring the `registrationIds` array. This should be done immediately before adding the ids. In addition, you should add the ids first, then send the notifications (once!), like [Salem suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20859728/1080564).

```
var registrationIds = [];
items.forEach(function(item) {
    registrationIds.push(obj[item].gcm_regid);
});
sender.send(message, registrationIds, 1, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```